# how to fix delete record using partial view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, modal-dialog, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I want to delete the record from the table with modal but the partial view is not displayed in modal ...
How can I solve this problem !?
And that I can not use onClick !!!

[image]

this action for delete in controller:

```
 public IActionResult DelPlatform(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        PR_Platform platformModel = _Iunit.PlatformsRepository.GenGetById(id);
        if (platformModel == null)
        {
           return NotFound();
        }
        return View(platformModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult DelPlatform(int id)
    {
        _Iunit.PlatformsRepository.GenDeleteById(id);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(PlatformList));
    }
```

this delete button in index view:

```
<a asp-controller="Platform" asp-action="DelPlatform" asp-route-id="@item.PlatformId" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal"><i class="mdi mdi-delete" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="حذف"></i></a>
```

this script for delete:

```
<script>
    (function ($) {
        function Delete() {
            var $this = this;
            function initilizeModel() {
                $("#delete-modal").on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
                }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
                });
            }
            $this.init = function () {
                initilizeModel();
            }
        }
        $(function () {
            var self = new Delete();
            self.init();
        })
    }(jQuery))
</script>
```

this modal (in shared folder):

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-center" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="delete-modal" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header text-danger">
            <h5 class="modal-title mt-0 text-white"><strong>حذف از پایگاه داده</strong></h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal-footer mr-auto">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">حذف شود</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this delete action view (for get record name):

```
@model PR_Platform
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<form asp-controller="Platform" asp-action="DelPlatform" method="post">
    <div class="modal-body" id="delete-modal">
        <p><strong>آیا از حذف <em>"@Model.PlatformName"</em> مطمئن هستید؟</strong></p>
        <p class="mb-0"><small>@Model.PlatformName از پایگاه داده حذف خواهد شد</small></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

View:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-center" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="delete-modal" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-danger">
                <h5 class="modal-title mt-0 text-white"><strong>حذف از پایگاه داده</strong></h5>
                <form asp-controller="Platform" asp-action="DelPlatform" method="post">
                    <div class="modal-body" id="delete-modal">
                        @*<em>"@Model.PlatformName"</em> <small>@Model.PlatformName از پایگاه داده حذف خواهد شد</small>*@
                        <p><strong>آیا از حذف  مطمئن هستید؟</strong></p>
                        <p class="mb-0"></p>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit">Click if you are sure to Delete</button>
                </form>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            @*<div class="modal-footer mr-auto">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">حذف شود</button>
                </div>*@
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@*asp-controller="Home" asp-action="DelPlatform" asp-route-id="@item.PlatformId"*@
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal">Click to Delete<i class="mdi mdi-delete" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="حذف"></i></a>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a whole working demo you could follow:

Model:

```
public class PR_Platform
{
    public int PlatformId { get; set; }
    public string PlatformName { get; set; }
}
```

Main View(Index.cshtml):

Add `data-id` in the anchor tag for getting the clicked value.

```
@model IEnumerable<PR_Platform>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
<a asp-controller="Platform" asp-action="DelPlatform" asp-route-id="@item.PlatformId" data-id="@item.PlatformId" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal"><i class="mdi mdi-delete" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="حذف"></i></a>
<a asp-controller="Platform" asp-action="DelPlatform" asp-route-id="@item.PlatformId" data-id="@item.PlatformId" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal"><i class="mdi mdi-delete" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="حذف"></i></a>
}   
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-center" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="delete-modal" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-danger">
                <h5 class="modal-title mt-0 text-white"><strong>حذف از پایگاه داده</strong></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                 //add this......
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer mr-auto">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">حذف شود</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS in main view:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
          (function ($) {
            function Delete() {
                var $this = this;
                function initilizeModel() {
                    $("#delete-modal").on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
                        var $button = $(e.relatedTarget); //Button that triggered the modal
                        var id = $button.data("id");  //get the id
                        alert(id);
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "/Platform/DelPlatform/"+id,                   
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                $(".modal-body").html(data);//load the response html code to the modal
                            },
                            error: function (e) {
                                alert('Error');
                            }
                        })
                    }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
                    });
               }
               $this.init = function () {
                    initilizeModel();
               }
           }
        $(function () {
            var self = new Delete();
            self.init();
        })
    }(jQuery))
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult DelPlatform(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    PR_Platform platformModel = _Iunit.PlatformsRepository.GenGetById(id);
    if (platformModel == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(platformModel);
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer ... but sent null object error (id = 0)

Comment: Hi @ghasemdeh, did you set `data-id="@item.PlatformId"` for the `<a>`?

Comment: Hi @Rena, Yes ... set this data-id="@item.PlatformId"

Comment: Hi @ghasemdeh , Maybe you need share the details about where these code locates and edit your original question. In my project I just put the launch modal button and modal code in the main view. The js code is also in the main view.